# Why is the ngIf directive on an HTTP observable updating the view on a page reload only?

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

I have a template:

```
<div *ngIf="(currentUser | async)?.can('book')">Book Now</div>
```

with its component:

```
readonly currentUser: Observable<CurrentUser>;
constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  this.currentUser = this.userService.whenAvailable();
```

and its service:

```
whenAvailable(): Observable<CurrentUser> {
  return combineLatest(this.userInfo, this.users).pipe(
    map(([user, users]) => users.find((u) => user.login === u.login)),
    map((user: UserInfo) => new CurrentUser(user))
  );
}
```

Either the user can book or cannot.

I log out and back in to change user.

But when changing user, the book `div` element is correctly displayed only after I reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

If the values are changing you could use the ChangeDetectorRef class provided by @angular/core.
Something like this:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component} from 
"@angular/core";

@Component({
 selector: "sample-comp",
 templateUrl: "./sample.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["./sample.component.scss"],
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {}


functionThatChangesSomeValue(){
  .....
  .....
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: I had tried the `ChangeDetectorRef` and it did not work. I now also tried the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` with it, and it didn't work either.

Comment: By the  way, what do you mean  with this `functionThatChangesSomeValue` ? I tried something like this `this.currentUser = this.userService
    .whenAvailable()
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this._onDestroy),
      tap((user) => {
        this.user = user;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
        console.log(user);
      })
    );`